# How to return multiple functions in if statement (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to return multiple functions for specific values, but it only returns the first function that I state. example:

```
if avatar == 'jeff' or avatar == 'Jeff':
        return hat('both')
        return face('true', '0')
        return arm('=')
        return torso(2)
        print('      HHHHH')
        return leg_and_shoe(2)
```

It will only return the first function, hat, for an input of 'both'.

Comment: `return` is always going to end the function, there and then. What where you hoping the caller would receive?

Comment: A return statement returns from a function (immediately). You can return a tuple for multiple values: `return firstThing, secondThing, ...`. You can also read about `yield`.

Comment: If the user enters 'jeff' or 'Jeff', they should receive a default ASCII avatar, but rather than print that avatar line by line I wanted to just return functions for the custom avatar function with the following inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This might accomplish what you want, but what Martijn said regarding return is true. Return will exit the function.

```
if avatar == 'jeff' or avatar == 'Jeff':
    return f"{hat('both')}\n{face('true', '0')}\n{arm('=')}\n{torso(2)}\n'      HHHHH'\n{leg_and_shoe(2)}"
```

Alternatively, you can call those functions separately within the function.. and then assemble your "final product" before returning it.. that's essentially what is being done with the f string I used above.